# How to handle click events in html(Html which is appended/replaced from another ajax call's data)

Tags: ajax

```
    $('.a').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'user':user},
            showLoader: true,
            success: function(response){
             ******Appending content from response*****
            }
        });
    });
```

After this, If I click on a button which is from that appended content it is not triggering the click event.
I tried adding .trigger("click"), didn't help though.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your appended button does not exist at the time of your on click binding, so no event is bound to these elements.

Try using the on function with a selector instead

```
$(document).on('click', '.a', function() {
    // DO STUFF
});
```

This binds the click event to all elements with the .a class, regardless if they exists at the time of binding or not.

http://api.jquery.com/on/